# Embeded resource copying but not running

Tags: vb.net, embed, temp

I am trying to copy my exe from resources to the temp folder and execute the new copy from there however my "Load Calculator.exe" is copying without a problem but not executing it (by that I mean `Process.Start`)

```
Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath, "Load Calculator INTL.exe")
Dim BytesToWrite() As Byte = My.Resources.Load_Calculator_INTL
Dim FileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
Dim BinaryWriter As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(FileStream)
BinaryWriter.Write(BytesToWrite)
BinaryWriter.Close()
FileStream.Close()
Process.Start(FileName)

'keepInvisible = False
'Me.Visible = True
Me.Close()
```

Comment: _What error do you get?_

Comment: Nothing the odd thing though is it is copying to the temp folder just not running te process from the temp folder?

Comment: Is it not running the process at all? Or is it running the process, but not from the temp folder?

Comment: its not running the process at all Im not on an english machien (dutch) the variable FileName is returning its answer in english where C:\Users is C:\Gebruikers in dutch, though that said it is coppying to the temp folder

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
        Using calc As New Process
            calc.StartInfo.FileName = FileName
            calc.Start()
        End Using
```

It's another way of opening files, and i use it very frequently.

~ Would have made this a comment, but until i reach 50 Rep, i cannot
comment so i hope this helps you with your problems.

Comment: Nope its stricktly doing it with the temp folder even if i manually type the path by hand its not responding hoever if i change the path to the C:\ it works but I need it to run from the temp folder?